# can't access libvirt_domain_create() function

Tags: libvirt

I am trying to start a virtual machine but there is an error occurring at the line on which libvirt_domain_create() function is called.

The error is:
Error while starting domain:operation forbidden: read only access prevents virDomainCreate

I am using root as a user and i have added root in the libvirtd and apache group in Centos7.

Please tell how to start the virtual machine in php-cli as this error is coming in php-cli.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing the code, but based on the error message it sounds like you explicitly opened the connection to libvirt in read-only mode.

Comment: OK,But in libvirtd.conf, i have already set the unix_sock_rw_perms="0770". But still the error is coming. Please tell how to set the connection with libvirt in read-write mode.